# Why does the Flash player crash in Firefox when setting a large height of it's container div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache-flex, flash

I have an Flex application being loaded in an HTML Div:

```
 <div id="flashContent" style="height: 350px;"></div>
```

like so

```
var so = new SWFObject("photoGallery.swf", "photoGallery", "100%", "100%", "9", "#FFFFFF");
    so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    so.addVariable("varLang", lang);
    so.write("flashContent");
```

I wanted the div's height to adjust to the content of the SWF, so from Flex I use `externalInterface.call()` to this Javascript function:

```
function loadPhotoGallery(newHeight)
{
    document.getElementById('flashContent').style.height = (newHeight + 70) + 'px';
}
```

Everything has been working fine until recently when the content (photo gallery) has gotten larger... Calling the `loadPhotoGallery` function with `newHeight` greater than 9000 crashes the Flash player using Firefox and  Safari. It works fine with Chrome. (Tested on a Mac). Is there a maximum height that is causing the crashes?

Comment: Could it be that you have still have Flash Player v10 installed? That had a limit of somewhere around 8100px I think. Chrome has its own Flash plug-in built in so if you have a recent Chrome, it will have v11. But Safari and FF will use the separately installed Flash plug-in (installed in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`).

Comment: I was on 11.5, and just upgraded and tried with 11.6 but still crashes.

Comment: The size limit in Flash Player 11 is [dependent on the OS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) (see the note at the bottom of the class info). You might try this on another platform as a test. Are you applying any filters or other effects to the image or doing any other sort of bit map manipulation? You're probably going to need to define an upper limit on the dimensions of the image (technically, it's the number of pixels in the image, not the dimensions: 9000x9000 may be too large, but 9000x1000 might be ok).

Comment: Also, as another test, you can try disabling Chrome's Pepper Flash plugin (go to: chrome://plugins, find the Flash plugin that has "pepper" in the path and disable it). Chrome should then use the same plugin as the other 2 browsers and crash in the same way -- not necessarily useful :) Interestingly, this would be the first time I've heard Pepper Flash do something better than the regular Flash plugin :)

Comment: Thanks @Sunil D. , it seems to make sense. But in my case it's a column of many images (not just a single image), and JPGs (not Bitmaps). Does the same dimension restriction apply? I am using a `DropShadowFilter` on each image. With multiple images, then I guess I should limit the number of images per page? Regarding Chrome plugin settings, it says "Adobe Flash Player (2 files) - Version: 11.6.602.180 Shockwave Flash 11.6 r602"... nothing about "pepper".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like Photosynth. This program can organize thousands of pictures  in a panorama-like viewing. You can have superb dimensions up to a gigapixel of processing power on the graphics accelerator.

Good luck!
Prolong the future of content delivery